# How to prove that total number of non-isomorphic labelled trees of order $n$ is $n^{n-2}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees, data-structure

I predicted the formula by finding total number of non-isomorphic labelled trees of order 1 is 1 , order 2 is 1,order 3 is 3,order 4 is 16,order 5 is 125.But how do i prove it ?
I am beginner in graph theory so i will be very thankful if i get some simple approach to solve the problem(Not by using some difficult theorems).

Comment: To get the right superscript to show up, use accolades, like so: `$n^{n-2}$` will typeset $n^{n-2}$.

Comment: There's a proof of this in a book by Arthur Engel, "problem solving strategies". I have the copy at home, and I'm not at home now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [Prüfer sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence); there is a bijection between labelled trees and length-$n-2$ sequences of numbers in $[1,n]$ (the Wikipedia article gives a good description of how to go from sequence to tree and back). Since there are $n^{n-2}$ such sequences, there are also this many labelled trees.

Comment: Wikipedia shows how, given a labelled tree $T$, to construct a Prüfer sequence for $T$. We may *define* Prüfer sequences so. So unequal Prüfer sequences can't have isomorphic labelled trees. Moreover, non-isomorphic labelled trees can't have equal Prüfer sequences. Suppose not; let $T_1, T_2$ be an example minimising $n$. There are labels $v$ and $w$ such that, in each case, the algorithm removes edge $vw$. By minimality of $n$, the respective results of removing $vw$ from each tree are isomorphic to some labelled tree $T_3$. So $T_1$ and $T_2$ are both isomorphic to $T_3+uv$.